# Resize parent menu jquery?

Tags: jquery, resize

I've been fiddling with jquery resize, although I can't seem to get the desired effect I need.

Basically, I have a menu which I want to resize with a button that floats to the right of the menu, once dragged it will resize the menu, I also want to limit the resize if possible!

Please help? Here's what I have so far :(

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/uGtat/

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

jQuery

```
$('#drag').disableSelection().draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $('#menu').width($(this).offset().left);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#menu').width($(this).offset().left);
    }
});​
```

CSS

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#drag, #menu {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}
#drag {
    width: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
​
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/gkMPA/

Comment: @user1560537 Thanks thanks. Remember to accept when available.

Comment: Just so you know! Not trying to belittle you at all, but with further research, because evidently this didn't do exactly what I needed, it did in my test, but when putting it in real practice it didn't work :( 

but the resizeable event has a few options you may not know about which fixed everything I was missing. 

.resizable({
        minWidth: 18,
        maxWidth: 750,
        maxHeight: 64
});

Comment: My goal was accomplished, you researched. :)